# MAX31865 - can I use a 150 ohm Rref?

Tags: temperature, rtd

I'm building a circuit for a home brewing application which will use the [MAX31865](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf) chip to read in temperatures of liquids from a RTD100 sensor.  The chip does this by reading the current that flows through the RTD and comparing it to the same current that flows through the reference resistor to get a ratio (and therefore the resistance value of the RTD which can be translated into the temperature).

The datasheet specifies that RRef should be 400Ω to cover the entire temperature range that the PT100 can handle (-200°C to 485°C), but I only need to cover from 0°C to 100°C, as the liquid will never go above that (it'll boil instead).  I thought I'd be able to specify a smaller resistor (say 150Ω) and get better precision from the 15 bit DAC, but the datasheet specifies a minimum R<sub>ref</sub> of 350Ω.

Does anyone have enough experience with this chip to tell me if a smaller value resistor would work? I know its a violation of the specs, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Too much current for the V<sub>bias</sub>?

In the end, I can use a 400Ω resistor if I need to, but I thought I'd see if I can optimise it.

Thanks!

Comment: I never used this particular chip, so I can't answer, but I strongly think you should bust trust the recommended operating conditions specified in the datasheet. Outside of it, there are no guarantees that the chip behaves as ut should. And even if someone says that he successfully used this very chip with 150Ohm, I still wouldn't try it. Maybe he was lucky, the chip came from a batch better than usual, but because of Murphy's law, you won't be so lucky and will realize only when your product is in the field.

Comment: One thought I just had - Use a PT1000 sensor instead of a PT100, then use a 1500 ohm resistor instead.  Win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 15 bit ADC with a resolution of 0.03125°C. Even if you only used one-sixteenth of the range you'd still get a resolution of about 0.5 °C and for beer making that's plenty close enough. Plus, consider what the RTD accuracy is?

Anyway, the data sheet says that bias voltage output current is 5.75 mA maximum and given the bias voltage is 2.06 volts maximum, that means the resistor can be no less than 358.3 ohms under the worst case scenario.

Comment: I understand the “it’s good enough” answers, but sometimes a bit more precision (if not necessarily accuracy) is useful, especially in the control circuit.  Thanks for the answer though on the vbias. That explains the data sheet minimum

Comment: That is why I added the bit that should settle the question. Good luck with the beer making.